# Can the repaired assembly machine use inserters?

Tags: factorio

In the tutorial, I tried and tried to place inserters next to the repaired assembly machines but nothing happens and I have to carry around the produced items by hand. Are inserters not supported for these repaired ones?

Comment: If you add a screenshot of what you're trying to your question, it'll likely be easier for someone to see what the problem is.

Comment: What I didn't understand when I posted the question is that the alignment/direction of the inserter needs to be orthogonal to the highlighted box of the receiving object. I wrongly aligned the inserter simply parallel to the repaired assembly machine.

Comment: [There is a mod for that!](https://mods.factorio.com/mod/bobinserters)

Comment: i'm confused, as i wrote I made it work without any mod?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press ALT.

You'll see that inserters have an entrance and exit marked by the arrow symbol. Inserters also work if they have something to get from the entrance and release that thing on the other way (on a belt for example). If they can't get rid of what they have grabbed then they will not work.